# How to build a CAML query with several nested OR's using a loop

Tags: development, caml-query

I'm new to SharePoint development and I need your help to solve this issue.I've created a `CAMLQuery` builder class.

```
public class CAMLQueryBuilder
{
    #region Builder part

public static string QueryBody(string clause1)
{
    return "<Where>" + clause1 + "</Where>";
}

public static string QueryAnd(string clause1, string clause2)
{
    return "<And>" + clause1 + clause2 + "</And>";
}
public static string QueryOr(string clause1, string clause2)
{
    return "<Or>" + clause1 + clause2 + "</Or>";
}

public static string QueryEq(string fieldName, string fieldType, string fieldValue)
{
    return string.Format("<Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}'/><Value Type='{1}'>{2}</Value></Eq>", fieldName, fieldType, fieldValue);
}
#endregion
}
```

Now I have `List<string>positions` which may contain more than one string, and for each position Employee can see some info regarding some rules(if he is office director , he can see everything from his office, if he is delivery manager everything from his department).Now I need idea how can I build multiple OR query after going through the for loop. I want a query that will have as many nested OR's as there are positions at the and of for loop.

This is the basic structure of the code, I need your help to make it work. I've created generic recursive method in case there will be more than one positions to generate nested OR's.

```
public static string RecursiveNestedOr(int count, List<string> query) 
{
//please if you have another idea for naming this method
   if (count == 1)
   {
       return query[0];
   }
    else
    {
      return CAMLQueryBuilder.QueryOr(query[count-1], RecursiveNestedOr(--count, query));
    }
  }
```

Then I make a query string for each of the position and add it to Listqueries.After that I use recursive method and send list of queries as a parameter to it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < positions.Count - 1; i++)
{
  switch (positions[i])
  {
    case ("OfficeDirector"): query = CAMLQueryBuilder.QueryEq("Office", "Choice", emp.Offices[i]);
       break;
    case ("DeliveryManager"): query = CAMLQueryBuilder.QueryEq("Department", "Choice", emp.Departments[i]);
       break;
    default:query = "";
       break;
  }
   queries.Add(query);

}
   query = CAMLQueryBuilder.QueryBody(CAMLQueryBuilder.RecursiveCAMLOr(queries.Count, queries));
//this is only basic idea
```

Is there any other solution ? More elegant ? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass `count` as a parameter as you can get it from `queries` Inside the method `RecursiveNestedOr` itself (also, rename parameter `query` as `queries`).

Otherwise, your recursion looks fine to me. Here's how I'd "simplified" it, using LINQ (add `using System.Linq`):

```
public static string RecursiveNestedOr(IEnumerable<string> queries)
{
    if (queries == null || queries.Count() == 0)
        return "";

   if (queries.Count() == 1)
       return queries.First();

    // Now queries.Count is at least 2
    return CAMLQueryBuilder.QueryOr(queries.Last(), RecursiveNestedOr(queries.Take(queries.Count() - 1)));
}
```

EDIT:
Here's how to do it without recursion (code not tested):

```
public static string NestedOr(IEnumerable<string> queries)
{
    if (queries == null || queries.Count() == 0)
        return "";

   if (queries.Count() == 1)
       return queries.First();

   string result = queries.First();

   // Now queries.Count is at least 2

   foreach(string query in queries.Skip(1))
   {
      result = QueryOr(result, query);
   }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Evariste great idea.However , this code has some errors, VS is showing Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int' , because Enumerable.Count is an extension method.So correct answer will be queries.Count(),

Comment: Yup, you're correct; or `.Length` probably. I edited my answer.

Comment: Do you know any other way for creating a nested OR query like this which is not a recursion ?

Comment: You could probably do it with a simple `for` loop, but that would be less elegant IMO. I code it as you do.

Comment: Updated my answer to provide a sample without recursion.